# Coverity report meanings - PW.INCLUDE_RECURSION

Tags: c++, coverity

After running the coverity on my C++ code I am getting the below categories of warnings. Can you please help me with details what are these and is there any documents for understanding these?

1. `PW.INCLUDE_RECURSION`
2. `WRAPPER_ESCAPE`
3. `PW.EXPR_HAS_NO_EFFECT`
4. `PW.QUALIFIER_IN_MEMBER_DECLARATION`
5. `PW.USELESS_TYPE_QUALIFIER_ON_RETURN_TYPE`
6. `PW.MISSING_TYPEDEF_NAME`
7. `PW.IMPLICIT_INT_ON_MAIN 8-OVERFLOW_BEFORE_WIDEN`

Thanks

Comment: Did you use Google? If yes, what did you found?

Answer (score 0):

Some I found on Google:

include_recursion — #include file "xxxx" includes itself

expr_has_no_effect — expression has no effect

qualifier_in_member_declaration — qualified name is not allowed
in member declaration

useless_type_qualifier_on_return_type — type qualifier on return
type is meaningless

missing_typedef_name — declaration requires a typedef name

implicit_int_on_main — return type "int" omitted in declaration of
function "main"

OVERFLOW_BEFORE_WIDEN - Evaluate integer expressions in a larger size before comparing or assigning to that size

Answer (score 0):

if you have Coverity installed on your machine, just to go to the checker reference,

C:\Program Files\Coverity\Coverity Static Analysis\doc\en\cov_checker_ref.pdf

C:\Program Files\Coverity\Coverity Static Analysis\doc\en\cov_checker_ref.html

search for those checker names and you can get good explanations on those parse warnings.